# Schematic to work with an SD card

Tags: pcb-design, stm32, schematics, decoupling-capacitor, sd

[The application note AN10911 from NXP](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/application-note/AN10911.pdf) contains several schematics for working with SD cards, for example the schematic shown below. However, it also states:

> This schematic does not include details concerning card-supply and typical power-supply
> decoupling capacitors.

What's the difference between "card-supply" and "power-supply", and where should those capacitors be put?

Would the schematic be complete after adding those capacitors? Assuming the host is STM32.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Card supply assumes that the SD card runs at a different voltage than your main host does.

Power supply decoupling caps are just that, the typical caps needed for any power supply and ic.

So yes, just adding the appropriate power supply for your SD card (I'm assuming 3.3V typical bug it could vary) and a 0.1uf close to the card and whatever other caps your supply needs, is all the extra you could typically expect to interface with an SD card.